# How to create dummie variables named by month and year based on a sequence of months applied over a dataset?

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm calculating the prevalence by month for a set of chronic conditions in a dataset of 885.630 patients. Every patient has three main pieces of information: (1) df$min, the date for the first appearance in the dataset; (2) df$max - last appearance in the dataset and; (3) df$HBP, with the date the patient was diagnosed for High Blood Pressure, for example. All three variables are dates. I created another variable called df$interval using the lubridate::interval function combining df$min & df$max to allow me to use the consider the patient in the denumerator only during that period of time. Each patient has specific df$min and df$max, creating some trouble to calculate the prevalences for every 82 months, since the numerator and denominator vary every new month and also a patient must be considered as "case" only during the period of time from df$condition until df$max for that particular patient.

I already solved the first part of the problem by creating dummy variables for every 82 months that will allow me to calculate the prevalences, but I'm sure there is an easier way to do it other than repeating 82 times the same line of code.

```
library(lubridate)
HBP <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2013-08-01", NA, "2017-11-01", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

min <- as.Date(c("2017-05-19", "2013-03-27", "2013-08-01", "2013-04-24", "2013-05-08", 
                 "2013-03-21","2013-04-08","2013-08-01","2016-09-12", "2016-06-13"))

max <- as.Date(c("2017-05-19","2014-09-12","2018-09-24","2013-04-24","2018-07-31",
                 "2018-04-17","2018-04-11","2017-02-07","2016-09-12", "2016-06-13"))

df <- data.frame(HBP, min, max)

month <- round_date(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-02-02"), as.Date("2018-11-08"), by = "months"), "month") # those are the min and max values of consultations in the dataset.


df$interval <- interval(df$min, df$max)

df$month1 <- month[1] %within% df$interval
df$month2 <- month[2] %within% df$interval
# repeat 82 times - here is my first issue: Is there am easier way to do it?
df$month65 <- month[65] %within% df$interval
```

As a result, the Dummy variables show TRUE (patient will be in the denumerator for that month) or FALSE. It's working, but I still have some questions:

1. What would be the easy way to create these variables "month1", "month2", "monthn"?
2. Is there a straightforward way to calculate the prevalences for every month without creating the dummies for every month? The result would be a dataframe with 82 rows (one for every month) and columns with the prevalence for every chronic condition.

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question only partially. You could create the dummy columns for the months as follows:

```
dummies <- lapply(month, function(x) {x %within% df$interval})
dummies <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(dummies), ncol = length(month)))
colnames(dummies) <- paste0("month", 1:length(month))
df <- cbind(df, dummies)
```

Comment: Thank you, Flavia. Your suggestion really solved the first question. With it, I was able to "colSums" every chronic condition and create a dataset with every month per row and one column for every chronic condition. `condition1 <- c(colSums(dummiescondition1, na.rm = TRUE))`, resulting in a data frame such as `df <- data.frame(month, pacient, condition1, condition2)`. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome, Adelson! Now I get better what do you want to do. You could simplify it quite a lot adding `sum` directly on the function on my first line of code to calculate directly the values of "condition": `condition <- lapply(month, function(x) {sum(x %within% df$interval)})`

Comment: It absolutely worked. At the end just `rbind.data.frame` helps to build the final df. You saved a lot of lines of code ;)

Comment: Glad it works! I suggest you to check on `mapply` in case you want to perform the analysis for more than one df with different conditions.